# why doesn't `nx` executor read specified `tsConfig`?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nx-monorepo

I am using `nx` to manage a package-based monorepo. I created a `project.json` file to use `@nx/jest:jest` to compile typescript code like below:

```
{
  "targets": {
    "test": {
      "executor": "@nx/jest:jest",
      "options": {}
    },
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/js:tsc",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig1.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when I run `npx nx build myapp`, it doesn't use the configuration from the file `tsconfig1.json`. It seems the build still uses a default configuration. How can I specify the `tsconfig` file in nx project?

my project structure:

```
apps/libs/myapp
nx.json
project.json
package.json
```

The `nx.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "nx/presets/npm.json",
  "$schema": "./node_modules/nx/schemas/nx-schema.json",
  "affected": {
    "defaultBase": "master"
  },
  "tasksRunnerOptions": {
    "default": {
      "runner": "nx/tasks-runners/default",
      "options": {
        "cacheableOperations": [
          "build",
          "lint",
          "test",
          "e2e"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "workspaceLayout": {
    "projectNameAndRootFormat": "as-provided"
  },
  "targetDefaults": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": [
        "^build"
      ],
      "executor": "@nx/js:tsc"
    }
  }
}
```